# Is there a way to load images with pthreads enabled in emscripten?

Tags: c++, emscripten

Whenever I try to compile a program with emscripten using `-sUSE_PTHREADS` and `-sSDL2_IMAGE_FORMATS`, I get the error `--shared-memory is disallowed by IMG_png.c.o because it was not compiled with 'atomics' or 'bulk-memory' features.`. Removing the `-sSDL2_IMAGE_FORMATS` option lets the code compile, but IMG_Init fails.

Here's the code I am using:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>

#include <thread>

void t() {
    printf("Other thread\n");
}

int main() {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG);

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("a", 0, 0, 50, 50, 0);

    SDL_Surface* surf = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
    SDL_Rect r;
    r.w = 50;
    r.h = 50;
    SDL_FillRect(surf, &r, 255);

    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
    

    printf("Loaded\n");

    std::thread thread(t);
    thread.join();
    
    printf("ended\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems like the problem is with the PNG library. Setting `-sSDL2_IMAGE_FORMATS` to just `svg` and using `IMG_Init(0)` lets you load SVGs, and pthreads works like normal.